# problems during linux kernel init

Tags: linux, kernel

What are the possible culprits for crashes during kernel init?

I am running a kernel that has initramfs, the inittab is very basic rcS (as sysinit) and getty (respawn). While booting I don't get any error message, however the init gives me this message:
S0 respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes, where S0 is actually the respawn::getty line(it seems as getty keep crashing), also none of the messages generated by the rcS are seen on the console (I assume that rcS commands also crashe).

If I force the kernel to go to /bin/sh (instead of /init) I can call rcS manually and I get no errors, same happens for getty (if I call getty with the same params from inittab it works fine).

I am wondering what are the difference between the way init spawns processes and the way /bin/sh does.

Comment: You need to provide the contents of your /etc/inittab. Leave out any comments and blank lines - just the guts.

Answer (score 0):

Some OS's log init respawns to wtmp, you might want to check there.  Turning up your syslog might also help.

When you kick off getty via /bin/sh, does it stay running?  AFAIK, the trick with init respawn is that the PID it generates is monitored and if it goes down it kicks off another one.

Comment: No, if I change the respawn to /bin/sh I get the same message " Respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes"

The only way i can avoid this is to execute /bin/sh instead of /init, also because the syslogs are mounted to the ramdisk I don't see any message.

Answer (score 0):

The stock /bin/sh is not built static, nor is getty.  You need to look at the 
shared library dependencies of /bin/sh and getty that all the libraries are present.

You can use ldd or 'readelf -a' to see the shared library dependencies.

Comment: I tried that, I am getting an Illegal instruction when trying to use ldd. I think something is fundamentally wrong with my distribution, I am wondering if I need to do anything special for DDR2 with 64 bits in linux kernel, this is the only change to the current eval board.

Comment: If you suspect your memory, you should try memtest from the install cd, most distros offer it in the boot/install menu.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe nothing is setting up `/dev/tty1`, `/dev/tty2`, etc, but stuff is running ok on `/dev/console` (which is not the same thing as `/dev/tty1`).  If you're depending on a /dev directory being in your initramfs or root filesystem, check those.

Probably the main difference between init=/bin/sh and letting init spawn stuff is the `/dev/console` vs. `/dev/ttyx`.  I can't think of anything else that would be relevant.  Keep in mind that the initramfs does run first, I think.

And BTW, you're obviously past the kernel init stage if init(8) or `/bin/sh` can run.